# Oracle eloqua form fields validation by an email

Tags: forms, email, eloqua

Is it possible to have a validation process with an email before updating a field from an eloqua form into the eloqua database ?

ex: my form integrates a field called "Persona" . This field is an important information so I want to be able to collect it in all Eloqua forms I produce. However, if I have already collected this information from a contact and this contact is entering a data in a new form which is not consistent from previous data stored I would like to be able to send him an email to ask him if he/she really wants to validate this new value before updating it? Is it possible to do this ? Has anyone done this in practice already ? Any feedback ?

Rgds

Xavier
Ps: prefilling is not always possible because some form respondents might come from social media and not be recognized by a cookie
Pss: once updated the field is updated once a night with Website contact database. An alternative is to capture this field from eloqua form only if this field was empty in eloqua. If not then a user needs to go to website contact database with password-based login to change the value. The drawback is that you have to create a web contact for each persone filling in an eloqua from and this may require minimum level of information you would not have asked in some of the eloqua forms otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You could prefill the data by performing a data lookup on the contact's email address (cookie or not). When the user completes their email address, use a script to lookup against the Eloqua contact database, and return the field values in the background. Upon submission of the form, do a diff check on the values entered vs the values you retrieved from the database. Output the result and submit that in another field through the form, then use that data after the fact. Maybe you could create an algorithm that sets a threshold for a significant change, set a boolean to true when that threshold is met, then trigger a campaign to send an email with their new values in the body, confirming if that is correct.